# btn-group with submenu twitterbootstrap

Tags: html, css, button, twitter-bootstrap

I'd like to know how can i build a btn-group with a sub-menu.

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
    Action
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <!-- dropdown menu links -->
  </ul>
</div>
```

and i' like to put this in the btn-group:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
  ...
  <li class="dropdown-submenu">
    <a tabindex="-1" href="#">More options</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      ...
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This is what i want: (but with twiiter-bootstrap)
[image: this is what i want]

Comment: From the Bootstrap docs: "Dropdowns in button groups - Heads up! Buttons with dropdowns must be individually wrapped in their own .btn-group within a .btn-toolbar for proper rendering." http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#buttonGroups

Comment: imagine that folders are buttons and has the menu and i want it to have a sub-menu.
Button -> Menu (items) -> Sub-Menu (+items)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Explanation: Basically this btn could go anywhere, I just put it in a button group to show there is nothing special about this button.

So first, you want to add data-toggle= dropdown to your button.  Then, you need to add your standard drop down menu to the button.  I guess the key here is knowing that there is nothing stopping you from adding a second dropdown menu into a submenu.

So go a head an add a submenu into whatever < li > you want, and inside that, just another dropdown-menu.  So essentially we have Button -> dropdown menu -> dropdown submenu -> dropdown menu -> sub elements.  Alittle confusing but pretty straight forward I think

```
<div class="btn-toolbar">
<div class="btn-group">

    <div class="btn-group">
      <!--start of dropdown button -->
      <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Button <span class="caret"></span></button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
         <li class="dropdown-submenu">
           <a tabindex="-1" href="#">More options</a>
           <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Regular link</a></li>
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Regular link</a></li>
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Regular link</a></li>
           </ul>
         </li>
     </ul>
    </div>
    <!--end of dropdown button -->
    <button class="btn">Middle</button>
    <button class="btn">Right</button>
</div>
</div>
```

## Edit:

After playing with this alittle, I realized that you do need the

```
<div class="btn-group">
```

wrapping the button, even if it is going to just stand alone.  I created this updated fiddle to demo it.
http://jsfiddle.net/jamiematthews/yWrRA/1/

Comment: There's no explanation here. Sure your solution might work, but this answer helps no one else but the OP if it's not explained

Comment: Sorry @bojangles, I added an explanation.  It's pretty straight forward, but I think my explanation should help further.  If something still is confusing, just let me know

Comment: Nice one. A quick read of the HTML makes apparent what you've done, I just feel that an explicit explanation of what's changed will help all future visitors no matter how good they are with HTML and/or Bootstrap

Comment: Definitely, also I commented where the actual button starts and ends, because that is most likely what people are interested in!

Answer (score 1):

Took a bit of experimenting but here's how you go about doing it:

http://jsfiddle.net/ewQTE/2/

```
<div class="btn-toolbar">
<div class="btn-group">

    <div class="btn-group">
      <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Left <span class="caret"></span></button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Dropwn Link #1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Dropwn Link #2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <button class="btn">Middle</button>
    <button class="btn">Right</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What I've done above is what you asked for as I understood it from your original question (before you posted the little graphic imag etc). I'm terribly terribly sorry that it's not what you want. 'sake.

Comment: sorry, for not being more explicit.

Comment: Big thanks to whoever downvoted this perfectly acceptable piece of code which was a valid interpretation of the OPs original post. Sleep well.